# Using IF statements to Search a Cell and Return a Value

Tags: excel, if-statement

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("XX-XXXXX-79",E2)), "True", "False")

I have also tried to use

=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("XX-XXXXX-79",E2)), "True", "False")

I am trying to use the following to search cell.

I am trying to find the last 2 values in the cell. If XX-XXXXX-79 then I want the value to return True. If XX-XXXXX-XX returns any value other than XX-XXXXX-79 then return False.

I can only get it to return a False value.

ANyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: `=IF(RIGHT(E2,2)="79","True","False")`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis thank you for the formula. It worked GREAT. I am still learning and always forget about the Right and Len functions. Far simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this do it for you?

=IF(RIGHT(E2,2)="79", "True", "False")

Comment: I see this was already answered in the comments! for reference, here's some more info https://spreadsheeto.com/text-functions/